# Zend PHPUnit var_dump not working in controllers

Tags: zend-framework, controller, phpunit, var-dump

I just ran into an unusual problem:
While testing controllers in Zend using PHPUnit, all of a sudden all occurrences of var_dump() placed in Controllers stopped working. In models and test-classes, they still show up, and when I navigate to the specified controller with a browser, all var_dumps are executed.

I'm completely at a loss here, does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already seen this link: http://tim.nyland-jones.co.uk/php/testing-controllers-with-zend_test-and-phpunit/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do with the Bootstrap.php, since that hasn't been changed at all. The var_dumps used to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the output is buffered.

You could do this in your Controller:

```
   error_log(print_r($var, true)); // instead of var_dump
```

or this in your test case:

```
  $return = $this->getFrontController()->getResponse()->getBody();
  var_dump($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try my "extended debug" class and use `dd($something);` ;)

https://github.com/tomasfejfar/enhanced-dump/blob/master/fnc.php